# How can I replace a character in a wordpress search query?

Tags: php, wordpress, replace, character

For example, how would I go about replacing `www.example.com/search/mark+twain` with `www.example.com/search/mark_twain` ?

The form to search looks like this:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>">
  <label class="visuallyhidden" for="s"><?php _e('Search for:', 'roots'); ?></label>
  <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php _e('Search Courses/Material'); ?> ">
  <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php echo attribute_escape(__('Search')); ?>" class="button">
</form>
```

Comment: mark+twain is totally different from mark_twain. Assume you have post with text "Mark Twain is a good man". WordPress search will show this post if search is "mark+twain" but it wont when the search is "mark_twain". Ideally you shouldn't be doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure how you're using this or where exactly you're using that query, but you could always use string replace:

`str_replace('+','_',$query)`

That's the best answer I can give with this vague a question.

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

For jquery (which wordpress makes use of) you could do something like:

`$('#sear form').submit(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(' ','_'));
});`

I think that's correct. I'm not where I can try it, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I'm editing a wordpress site, and for some reason search results don't show up without an underscore between words. I edited above to be more specific.

Comment: @Tim - Do you know where the form is being processed at? That's where you would do the string manipulation.

Comment: I don't. It's wordpress, and I'm trying to make it so that I only have to edit themefiles though, which is just front end stuff, so I'm thinking I can do this with jQuery instead.

Comment: If you are going to use jQuery as suggested above you should replace ' ' space with '_'. + is added as replacement for space.

Comment: Also replace the space upon form submit instead of keyup. User will be confused upon seeing + when what he typed is space.

Comment: @tamilsweet - good points. Updated to reflect your suggestions.